# How to find the limit to an undefined point (asymptotic)

Tags: limits

I am wondering about:

$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow -1} \frac{x+1}{ \sqrt{x+5}-2 } $$

which seems to be an asymptotic function with each side of its corresponding graph approaching negative or positive infinity at the value of *-1*.

Solved by WolframAlpha, the expected result was calculated:
[Click to see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFl5r.png).

So, I was just learning for a math exam and using the website KhanAcademy to refresh my math skills, where above term was to be solved, and indeed a two-sided limit should be found, which apparently seems to be *4*.

This was done by first rationalizing the term [in this manner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JLhW.png), which results in:
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow -1}( \sqrt{x+5}+2)\text{ for  }x \neq -1 $$

Substituting x for -1 in this simplified term doesn't result in getting $\frac{0}{0}$ but *4*, which apparently means that 4 is the both-sided limit (even though the root of 4 has 2 as well as -2 as the possible solution, making 0 another viable limit?). I can't proof which one of those two approaches contains an error and therefore wanted to ask here, I hope someone can clarify this matter :)

Best regards

Comment: the limit you wrote on wolfram is different from the limit in the text

Comment: Well, $\sqrt{5+x}$ has two potential values, but as a function we always take the positive one.  The limit is meaningless if $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a multivalued thing.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is $4$, in fact:
$$  \lim_{x \to -1}\frac{x+1}{ \sqrt{x+5}-2 }=\lim_{x \to -1} \frac{x+1}{ \sqrt{x+5}-2 }\frac{\sqrt{x+5}+2}{\sqrt{x+5}+2}=\lim_{x \to -1}\frac{(1+x)(\sqrt{x+5}+2)}{x+1} $$
The last limit is equal to:
$$\lim_{x \to -1}\frac{(1+x)(\sqrt{x+5}+2)}{x+1}=\lim_{x \to -1}(\sqrt{x+5}+2)=2+2=4 $$

Answer (score 2):

No need of l'Hôpital here. Considering the function
$$g(x)=\sqrt{x+5},\quad g'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{x+5}},$$
just notice that
$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt{x+5}-2}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{g(x)-g(-1)}{x-(-1)}=g'(-1)=\frac14,$$
hence your limit is the inverse, i.e. $4.$

Answer (score 0):

You computed the wrong limit in Wolfram:

$$4=\lim_{x \to -1}\frac{x+1}{ \sqrt{x+5}-2 } \neq \lim_{x \to -1}\frac{1}{ \sqrt{x+5}-2 }$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach it (according to the L'Hôpital rule):
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{x + 1}{\sqrt{x + 5} - 2} & = \lim_{x\to-1}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x + 5}}} = \lim_{x\to-1}2\sqrt{x + 5} = 4
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!